# Error Generating Report File (Reporting WebForms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

Please help, I'm having the following exception when trying to generate Excel file with Microsoft Reporting library in C# asp.net app:
**Message** ->  `An error occurred during local report processing.`

**StackTrace** ->  `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession() at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, CreateAndRegisterStream createStreamCallback, Warning[]& warnings) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.InternalRender(String format, Boolean allowInternalRenderers, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, PageCountMode pageCountMode, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Report.Render(String format, String deviceInfo, String& mimeType, String& encoding, String& fileNameExtension, String[]& streams, Warning[]& warnings)`

Code reference:

```
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = pathReportFile;
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamids;
string encoding;
string filenameExtension;
byte[] renderedBytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);
```

The exception jumps in line `byte[] renderedBytes = reportViewer...`

Comment: Please add a code so I'll be able to help you.

Comment: I've just added, the problem is in line `byte[] renderedBytes = reportViewer...`

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: Your rdlc report file may contain errors in one or more expressions. Remove all expressions and try again. Then add one at t a time back in.